# Multiple classes Robcode .NET

Tags: c#, .net, robocode

So i have an assigment where i am going to program an AI using Robocode with .NET C#. Using what i have learned at school, i want to create a few classes for different state machines.

In each class i have a update method that takes in an advanced robot. I then tried to create a instance of the robot i have, and send it in to the method.

```
    evadeState.update(robot);
```

The problem is that nothing is happening. And yes, i do have an endless loop. I believe my attempt is in the wrong direction, but i have no idea how else to do it.

So my question is, how do i use multiple classes with robocode?

Comment: Can you please show us a bit more code - you say you have an endless loop - where?

Comment: Code added. Wanted to avoid it, given that the assigment will most likely check for plagiarism.